# Meson, how to get include directoris of external dependency?

Tags: c++, build-system, meson-build

I have a subproject in meson that uses imgui. Due to a bug in meson, I have to override a command line argument for imgui, otherwise things won't compile:

i.e. I do something like this:

```
imgui_lib = library(
    'imgui',
    sources : [imgui_sources],
    dependencies : [dependency('imgui')],
    include_directories : [
        '../../../ext/imgui/bindings'
    ],
    cpp_args : ['-DIMGUI_USER_CONFIG="imgui_user_config.h"'])
imgui_dep = declare_dependency(
    link_with:imgui_lib,
    include_directories: [
        '.',
        imgui_bindings,
    ])
```

The bug is that meson deletes quotations in variables so `-DIMGUI_USER_CONFIG="imgui_user_config.h"` becomes `-DIMGUI_USER_CONFIG=imgui_user_config.h`

Which is trivially wrong and causes compilation errors.

This works fine, however it requires me to repeat this pattern whenever I use imgui, i.e. I have to do that override every single time, which is not fun.

I want, as part of my `imgui_dep` object for the imgui path to be part of the includes, i.e. I want something like:

```
imgui_dep = declare_dependency(
    link_with:imgui_lib,
    include_directories: [
        '.',
        imgui_bindings,
        imgui.get_include_dirs()
    ])
```

So far I tried:

`imgui.get_variable('includedir')`

But this results in the error:
`ERROR: Could not get pkg-config variable and no default provided for <PkgConfigDependency imgui: True None>`

All I want is the path to the include directories in that dependency, that's it, how do I fetch them?

Comment: Is `imgui` subproject or there is other subproject that uses `imgui`?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is simple:

```
my_lib_inc_dir = './my_lib/includes'

# Create dependency
my_lib_dep = declare_dependency(
  dependencies: my_lib,
  include_directories: include_directories(my_lib_inc_dir)
)
```

And then just link your lib with this dependency and it pulls include dir location automatically.